# How to see which varient is in use?

Tags: panels

Is there any way to know which Panel varient is being used, when I'm viewing the node or term? I know there is the panel page listing and that shows the varients, but it is difficult to know which nodes are using this varient.

I'm asking because I have a site, node template panel has over 20 different varients, some are in use some are not. Attempting to document them is painful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way, but when I've had to do this I just change the page title for each variant.  Of course, you probably don't want to do this on a live site, but if you have a test site it's not so bad.

Alternately, you could also add a CSS class, etc.

Comment: I was gonna suggest a css class as well. It would of course be nice if there was an easy way to put a token of some variant name on each page also, but I'm not aware of a way to do this.

Comment: So one potential solution is to add a css class to the varient, so by simply inspecting the page you can tell which varient it is.